# Custom form with link to document

Tags: 2010, development, document-library, custom, custom-form

I have a custom form. In it I need to add a link to a document library. I need that this links works in the same way as a link in a document library (i.e. - when you click on it you have the option to open as Read Only or Edit. or if this is not possible, users should be able to switch to edit mode when the document is opened).

Is this possible technically?

Answer (score 0):

The option to read only or edit will be displayed if the library requires check out before editing. Check the library settings.